# R / ggplot2: Can't change scale limits with dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to change the scale limits of a date-based x axis using `scale_x_continuous`, but `ggplot2` won't accept my new limits.

Example::

```
mydata <- tibble::tibble(
    x = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05")),
    y = 1:5
)

mydata_sub <- mydata[2:4,]

g <- ggplot2::ggplot(mydata_sub, ggplot2::aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    ggplot2::geom_point()

g <- g + ggplot2::scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(mydata$x), max(mydata$x)))

print(g)
```

This leads to the error message:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Am I using the wrong `scale_` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your x-axis is in a date format, you need to use `scale_x_date` to manipule your x axis:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata_sub, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(limits = c(min(mydata$x), max(mydata$x)))
```

[image]